# convert String to unsigned long long

Tags: arduino-mega, string, convert

i want to convert string for example 
"68976543210" to unsigned long long(64 bit) in mega2560,
 do is possible?

```
String x="68976543210";
unsigned long long y=?;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

avr-libc lacks `strtoull()` that I would normally use for such a conversion. You will have to do it manually.

Fortunately it's quite simple - just start with y=0 and, for each character in the string, multiply y by 10 then add the numeric value of the character in the string:

```
String x = "68976543210";
unsigned long long y = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    char c = x.charAt(i);
   if (c < '0' || c > '9') break;
   y *= 10;
   y += (c - '0');
}
```

Note that the Arduino Print API has no method for printing a 64-bit integer.